# viewDidGetCoveredUpByModalPresentationFormSheet?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have an app that has different integrations such as Evernote and Dropbox. When the user authenticates them, a UIViewController presents the authentication view as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet. This doesn't trigger viewDidDisappear for my view which makes sense since it doesn't disappear.

Is there another method I can implement that will be notified?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know when the modal view as been presented? Assuming you are using presentViewController:animated:completion , you can use the completion handler to know when the viewcontrollers view has been presented [Here is a ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)